# I cannot use drupal_set_message() in a custom controller module

Tags: 8, page-controller

In a custom controller, when I try to use `drupal_set_message()`, it works only if I use the following code.

```php
// The message is shown via {{ page.highlighted }}.
drupal_set_message('Test error', 'error');

return [
   '#type' => 'markup',
   '#markup' => "Welcome",
];
```

When I use the following code, it doesn't work.

```php
drupal_set_message('Test error', 'error');

return [
   '#type' => 'page',
   '#markup' => "Welcome",
];
```

I need to set `#type` to *page* to be able to inject custom variables.

Can anybody help me to understand how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try the following code.

```php
return [
  '#theme' => 'ctr',
  '#myvar' => 'myvalue',
];
```

The module needs also to implement `hook_theme()`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function ctr_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $variables = array(
    'ctr' => array(
      'template' => 'cntr',
      'variables' => array(
        'myvar' => 'defaultvalue',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $variables;
}
```